# Why can't I turn this object into an instance variable?

Tags: objective-c

I have a object I want to turn into an instance variable.  This works:

```
ZipFile *newZipFile = [[ZipFile alloc] initWithFileName:zipPath mode:ZipFileModeCreate];
```

But when I try to change it to this it doesn't work:

.h:

```
@interface PanelController : NSWindowController <NSWindowDelegate> {
  ZipFile *_zipFile;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) ZipFile *zipFile;
```

.m:

```
@synthesize zipFile = _zipFile;
...
// get a syntax error here
zipFile = [[ZipFile alloc] initWithFileName:zipPath mode:ZipFileModeCreate];
```

EDIT: I was able to fix this by putting this in my interface and getting rid of the @property:

```
ZipFile *newZipFile;
```

I guess I can't assign setters and getters to just any object?  But why won't it work if I do:

```
ZipFile *zipFile;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no ivar named `zipFile`. Did you mean:

```
_zipFile = [[ZipFile alloc] initWithFileName:zipPath mode:ZipFileModeCreate];
```

or:

```
self.zipFile = [[[ZipFile alloc] initWithFileName:zipPath mode:ZipFileModeCreate] autorelease];
```

**Note:** You probably want your property to be `retain`. `assign` is for properties you do not own (like delegates). `assign` properties are unsafe because can easily become dangling pointers.

Answer (score 3):

```
@synthesize zipFile = _zipFile;
...
// get a syntax error here
zipFile = [[ZipFile alloc] initWithFileName:zipPath mode:ZipFileModeCreate];
```

Your `@synthesize` says that your property is named `zipFile`, but the variable backing it is `_zipFile`.

You have no `zipFile` variable, so the assignment line is wrong.

```
_zipFile = [[ZipFile alloc] initWithFileName:zipPath mode:ZipFileModeCreate];
```

is correct.